# Plugin exporting Jira Confluence page(s) to LaTeX

Tags: pdftex

Is there any plugin or suggestion solution to export Jira Confluence pages to LaTeX files?

Our company is using Jira Confluence as a systems documentation resource and we document all of our designs there. And then we have a need to export all those design documents into PDF file so that we can send it to our customer.
Currently, we have to export them to .docx files, modify the styling (ex: chapter numbering) and finally convert to pdf. With this approach, the content comparison between two Word files (versions) is totally impossible as they are binary files. That's why we are thinking using some text-based file such as LaTeX for easier managing the versions as well as great styling for the final pdf.

- Updated:
  Jira Confluence is a content collaboration software, developed by Atlassian:
  https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence

Comment: What is "Jira Confluence"?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.stepstonetech.confluence.plugins.latex/server/overview)? I can only guess since you did not introduce us to  Jira Confluence.

Comment: I updated the question for "Jira Confluence".

Comment: No, I do not mean this plugin[https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.stepstonetech.confluence.plugins.latex/server/overview], it injects latex content into a Confluence page. I am looking for a way to export one page into latex format so that I can modify, compare them easier. Confluence already supports exporting to pdf, docx, xml ... but those are not easy to manage. Thanks.