# How to insert latex into confluence page?

Tags: documentation

I have some equations that I need to incorporate into a confluence page.  How do I do this in confluence?

Even if I have to use markdown, that is fine.  but I do not see a way to do that.

I see this post:  [Plugin exporting Jira Confluence page(s) to LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388910/plugin-exporting-jira-confluence-pages-to-latex)

But that is for export *to* LaTeX, whereas I want to go the otherway:  I want to inject LaTeX *into* a confluence page.  How do I do that?

I tried this: https://hiltmon.com/blog/2017/01/28/mathjax-in-markdown/.  But even the eaxmples in that page do not work.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks :)  Sorry...I saw it in the other question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388910/plugin-exporting-jira-confluence-pages-to-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1  so I figured the topic was still fair game for the TeX.SE.  no?

Comment: You can use texlive and standalne documentclass to export the equations in pdf format with pdflatex command and then convert them to png images with convert command. See here for more: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible

Comment: In that other question the other direction is mentioned in a comment, pointing to https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.stepstonetech.confluence.plugins.latex/server/overview.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using an appon like LaTeX EASY math equation for Confluence.
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1224024

It is easy to use and even it supports Live preview & edit.
Please check a youtube clip which shows how to use it.